# Exporting data to excel PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I am new to PHP & MySQL.

From my application I want to export data to excel.

Database is MySQL.

Data I want to export is coming from two tables.

Eg.

Customer:

```
- ID Name Address Phone#
- 1  Cust1 Add1   1234567890
- 2  Cust2 Add2   9012345678
```

Orders:

```
- ID CustID Revenue OrderDate
- 1  1      100     2018-01-01
- 2  1      200     2018-01-02
- 3  2      50      2018-01-03
```

I want to export following data to excel.

Name of Customer, Revenue & Order Date.

I have following queries:
1) Will exporting data to Excel using PHP code be better or should I create Procedure in MySQL to perform this job? which one will be better?

2) I have to import the same excel back to the database wherein if exported excel has any modification to revenue then I should update MySQL table with the updated revenue. In this case, will a procedure be better? I think for this operation procedure will be better but for above #1 I am not sure.

Can you please advise?

Comment: To ask an On Topic question, please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [retake the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: I am sorry if it did not meet the requirements, but since I am new to PHP and MySQL and I am not sure of what should be used. It is indeed requirements of project and hence I have asked in this forum. If you can please help let me know.

Comment: Do a search for `phpSpreadsheet` and read the doc. That should be very helpful to you

Comment: @RiggsFolly, unable to make use of phpSpreadsheet as per documentation. Composer is failing. If anyone has any link / video guiding usage of phpSpreadsheet with sample please do share. I found many videos using phpExcel but it is deprecated.

Comment: You can download a zip from github if you dont want to/cannot use composer

Comment: Thanks RiggsFolly, I managed to run composer by upgrading PHP version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by RiggsFolly, I am able to achieve the desired result using PhpSpreadsheet.

Downloaded from the following URL:
[https://github.com/PHPOffice/phpspreadsheet][1]

Installed it using composer.

Created two PHP files,
 1. ExportToExcel.php
 2. ImportFromExcel.php

Included reference to phpspreadsheet.

Use Spreadsheet() instance to perform the task.

If anyone needs code, please msg me.

I am able to export very fancy excel file to the end user by applying various formatting, coloring, introduced protection to sheet by allowing only few cells to be edited by end user etc.

While reading the excel file, setting readonly to ignore fancy formatting (which gives better performance as my requirement is to read only the data and not format).